# If condition returned by a LINQ query checked multiple times

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query I am using to see if events are out of order when returned ordered by a date and time.

```
            var itCompareDay = (from h in db.DailyGPSTables
                                where h.EmplID == EmpID
                                     && (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(h.EventDateTime) >= startDate.Date)
                                     && (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(h.EventDateTime) <= endDate.Date)
                                     && (h.EventType == "SS" || h.EventType == "JS" || h.EventType == "LS" || h.EventType == "LE" || h.EventType == "JE" || h.EventType == "SE")
                                orderby h.EventDateTime
                                select h).ToList();
```

I then check each item to see if it is in the correct order for the day.

```
       for (int l = 0; l <= itCompareDay.Count - 1; l++)
        {
       if (itCompareDay[l].EventType == "SS" && (itCompareDay[l].EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString()==startDate.Date.ToShortDateString()))
       {
       Response.Write("<br>"+ l +"   " + itCompareDay[l].EventType +" is'SS' and dates match" + itCompareDay[l].EventDateTime.Value.ToShortDateString() +"=" + startDate.Date.ToShortDateString() + "<br>");
       for (int j = 0; j <= itCompareDay.Count - 1; j++)
        {
        //Response.Write("<br>: If this " + itCompareDay[l].EventType + itCompareDay[l].EventDateTime.Value + " is greater than " + itCompareDay[j].EventType + itCompareDay[j].EventDateTime.Value);
        if (itCompareDay[l].EventDateTime.Value > itCompareDay[j].EventDateTime.Value)
        {
           Session["EOOmessage"] = "On " + itCompareDay[l].EventDateTime.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + " " + itCompareDay[l].EventType + " is After " + itCompareDay[j].EventType;
           Session["rowNumber"] = rowNumber;
           return false;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

While this seems to work it takes a performance hit because it checks the if statement for each item returned in the main query. I have 200 conditions to check.

I tried a for loop and a foreach loop and many other concoctions which have returned the same results. I tried removint the toList() and adding a linq query to the if statement also. Wits end is close by.

Comment: You don't need to use nested loops. Just a single loop is required to check if an element is out-of-order. For each iteration, you just need to keep track of the previously iterated element. Compare the previously iterated element with the currently iterated element to check whether they are out-of-order or not...

Comment: Why are you trying to validate if `orderby` actually works correctly? Also, when `l > 0` wouldn't you expect all `j < l` to trigger your `if`?

Comment: @NetMage I am trying to see if, for example SS(Shift Start) has a time greater than SE(Shift End) for a day. If this is true return false.

Comment: @elgonzo if I try without the loop how would I evaluate itCompareDay[l].EventType == "SS"?

Comment: Is the `Response.Write` really in this loop? Seems like taking that out would help with timing.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan No, it's for debugging only.

Comment: Think of what the purpose of your `if` clause with `itCompareDay[l].EventType == "SS"` is. Don't think in terms of what you have implemented there, think of what purpose it actually serves: It skips some elements in the sequence based on some criteria (the criteria being the expression used in the `if` statement). By the way, i did not say "_without a for loop_". I said "_Just a single loop_" -- you would still need a loop (or some Linq construct to iterate the sequence of elements), but there is no need to use an inner nested loop...

Comment: Isn't this statement, with what you said in comments, patently wrong? `(itCompareDay[l].EventDateTime.Value > itCompareDay[j].EventDateTime.Value)
` This will compare the current SS to everything...don't you want a sub loop of just the SE values?

Comment: Could you have more than one "SS" on a given day? Can you provide some sample data and a clear explanation of what you are attempting in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Remove a good chunk of the operations by weeding out what will be compared. Also to compare the dates use the `Date` property *instead of a string compare*.

Finally use the linq method `Any` which returns true if any 1 item/*the first item* meets the criteria.

```
var comparedToDates = itCompareDay.Where(dy => dy.EventType == "SE")
                                  .Where(dy => dy.Date >= startDate.Date)
                                  .ToList();
return
   itCompareDay.Where(dy => dy.EventType == "SS")
               .Where(dy => dy.Date == startDate.Date); // Compare this way instead 
               .Any(SS => comparedToDates.Any( SE => SS > SE )); // Let it 
                                                                 // work the compare
```